# Buffon's Needle experiment

Tags: java, random, simulation, numerical-methods

I was working on a program that simulates the Buffon's Needle experiment. If anyone is not familiar with it, a Wiki link is provided -  [Buffons's Needle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle)

The point of Buffon's experiment is to find the value of pi, or at least approximate it. Usually you draw a couple of lines and then you scatter pins around the board in which you drew the lines in, the more pins the better. Then you take the number of pins crossing the lines and divide that by the number of pins you first had and multiply that by 4.

Below, I have provided the code for my program which is written in Java. Right now, it seems as if there are too many variables/methods. Could someone help refine it so it functions and looks better?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class buffonNeedle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("How many darts do you want in each trial?");
        int darts = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many trials do you want conducted?");
        int trials = in.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i<trials; i++) {
            xVal(darts);
            yVal(darts);
            hits(darts);
            System.out.println(piCalc(darts));
        }
    }
    public static double [] xVal (int darts){
        double [] xVal = new double[darts];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i<darts; i++){
            xVal[i] = -1+random.nextDouble()*2;
        }
        return xVal;
    }
    public static double [] yVal (int darts){
        double [] yVal = new double[darts];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i<darts; i++){
            yVal[i] = -1+random.nextDouble()*2;
        }
        return yVal;
    }
    public static int hits (int darts){
        int hits = 0;
        double [] xVal = xVal(darts);
        double [] yVal = yVal(darts);
        for(int i = 0; i<darts; i++){
            if((Math.pow(xVal[i],2)+Math.pow(yVal[i],2))<=1){
                hits++;
            }
        }
        return hits;
    }
    public static double piCalc(int darts){
        double hits = hits(darts);
        double pi = (hits/darts)* 4;
        return pi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In this loop…

> ```
>     for(int i = 0; i<trials; i++) {
>         xVal(darts);
>         yVal(darts);
>         hits(darts);
>         System.out.println(piCalc(darts));
>     }
> ```

You are throwing away the values returned from `xVal(darts)`, `yVal(darts)`, and `hits(darts)`, making these calls completely superfluous.  All they are doing is wasting entropy from the random number generator.  The only thing that matters is `piCalc(darts)` (which calls `hits()`, which in turn calls `xVal()` and `yVal()`).

The code for `xVal()` is exactly identical to `yVal()`.  You don't need to write the same function twice.

Comment: But, without it, the program ceases to run.

Comment: @VishvakSeenichamy Just replace all yVal with xVal in the program.

Comment: @Caridorc what do you want me to replace them with?

Comment: @VishvakSeenichamy I am not sure maybe coordinate ?

Comment: I took out the Xval Yval and hits from the main method and it still works really well!

Answer (score 5):

**Avoid assignement just before returning**

> ```
> public static double piCalc(int darts){
>       double hits = hits(darts);
>       double pi = (hits/darts)* 4;
>       return pi;
> }
> ```

Should become:

```
public static double piCalc(int darts){
      return ((double)hits(darts) / darts) * 4;
}
```

Whenever you see

```
var = expression
return var
```

Go for this simplification.

**Long descriptive names**

`hits` is better named `is_crossing_line?` (Java does not allow `?` in names so you will have to remove it) and `xVal` should be named `get_coordinate` but I am not sure of the latter. As a rule of thumb if you have got a 5 or less letter name, think about something more descriptive.

Comment: Shouldn't it better be `isCrossingLine` and `getCoordinate` according to Java convention? And I don't agree 100% to _"5 or less"_ (depending on how big your thumb is :-) The keyword is "descriptive".

Comment: @GeroldBroser Sure it would be.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Sure in fact if a function performs little duty the name can be short, anyway especially with auto-completion I prefer longer names.

Comment: @DavidArno exactly, I lack experience with static typing. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

Why even create the `xVal` and `yVal` arrays?  And why recreate a `Random` object every time?

You could take a different approach by calculating the data and determining if it was a hit all in one go.  I also changed the function name from `piCalc` to `calcPi` so it reads a little better, and used the try-with-resources feature of Java 1.7 on `Scanner`.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuffonNeedle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
            System.out.println("How many darts do you want in each trial?");
            int darts = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("How many trials do you want conducted?");
            int trials = in.nextInt();

            for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(calcPi(darts));
            }
        }
    }

    private static double calcPi(int darts)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        int hits = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < darts; i++)
        {
            double xVal = Math.pow(-1 + random.nextDouble() * 2, 2);
            double yVal = Math.pow(-1 + random.nextDouble() * 2, 2);
            if ((xVal + yVal) <= 1)
            {
                hits++;
            }
        }

        return 4.0 * hits / darts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however I was given a set of rules to create the program and I was told to have separated methods for random number creation and then calculation

Answer (score 1):

- You're mixing spaces-around-operators style. Best practices is to use spaces for better readability.
- It's also best practices to let statements like `if`, `for`, ... be followed by a space to distinguish them from method invocations.